# I need to detect all state changes in DataBase

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of addresses, I have to detect each one separately when the state changed. The database looks as follows:  TimeSpan, Address, IsBusy. And I have to do it this way (sorted by TimeSpan):

```
Address  IsBusy
610      0
610      1   <--
610      0
750      0
610      0
610      0
750      1   <--
610      1   <--
610      1
750      0
610      0
610      1   <--
750      0
610      0
```

I need to detect places where the value 0 has changed to 1, for each Address.

I have absolutly no idea how to do this with SQL
thank you

Comment: mysql version ??

Comment: What is timespan?

Comment: Version is 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1,  TimeSpan it's a Unix time (Timestamp in milliseconds), I use

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             (select a2.isbusy
              from addresses a2
              where a2.address = a.address and
                    a2.timespan < a.timestamp
              order by t2.timestamp desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_isbusy
      from addresses a
     ) a
where a.isbusy = 1 and a.prev_isbusy = 0;
```

Or:

select a.*
from address a
where a.isbusy = 1 and
      (select a2.isbusy
        from addresses a2
        where a2.address = a.address and
              a2.timespan < a.timestamp
        order by t2.timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) = 0

This is much simpler in MySQL 8+:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lag(isbusy) over (partition by address over order by timestamp) as prev_isbusy
      from addresses a
     ) a
where a.isbusy = 1 and a.prev_isbusy = 0;
```